# SQL cursor index not moving to first even if .moveToFirst() is called

Tags: android, database, cursor

Hi i've been searching for this problem for quite some time now i am getting this "**android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0"**
so what i did is i call moveToFirst and logs if it didnt move to first

```
public void addImg(String playerName, String imgPath){
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(" SELECT " + PLAYER_ID + " FROM " + PLAYER_TBL + " WHERE " + PLAYER_NAME + "='" + playerName + "'", null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
           int pathIndex = c.getColumnIndex(PLAYER_ID);
           int playerId = c.getInt(pathIndex);
           ContentValues image = new ContentValues();
           image.put(PLAYER_IMG_ID, playerId);
           image.put(PLAYER_IMG_PATH, imgPath);
           db.insert(PLAYER_IMG_TBL, null, image);
       } else {
           Log.v("test", "not move to first");
       }

  }
```

but still it dont go inside the if statement it still goes in the else... any hints or help would be greatly appreciated.. thanks :)

Comment: I guess cursor is empty

Comment: how can i check that?

Comment: You can test your logic somewhat by temporarily taking out your where clause.  Or alternative, copy your database to your dev machine and do the query with a tool like SQLite Expert Personal 3

Comment: @NoobMe you check that just by what you are doing already, if `c.moveToFiest()` returns false that means the cursor is empty

Comment: @tyczj yes it is empty can do you have any clue's on how i can make it not empty? thank you so much~

Comment: @NoobMe put something in your database that fits that query

Comment: Create database and add some values